# My surroundings are dark, everywhere - how do I fix this bug?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

Wherever I go, my surroundings are always dark.
I have been experiencing this bug since the start of the game. This screencap shows what happens:

[image: at training ground]

Also [this video](http://www.mediafire.com/download/3ok88i5v0ntjc67/BatmanOrigins_2013-11-10_15-46-39-63.mp4) (2MB) might explain the problem.

How I can fix this problem? I've installed all of the support programs including PhysX & VC++, but the issue persists.

Comment: did you try changing the brightness in game itself?

Comment: @Novarg texture is totally disappear.nothing changes regardless of brightness level.

Comment: @Novarg: That appears to be a lighting issue, not a brightness issue.  mpower, the only suggestion I have would be to mess with the video settings to see if anything works.  Short of that, you'll likely have to wait for a patch.

Comment: @sheep2013 - Provide a `dxdiag` report if you don't mind.

Comment: I think this is not a good idea.that shows everything in my pc! but know that it's not a low-end system and surly can play this game prefect.

Comment: that guy (sheep2013) said he bought a cracked version and has same problem.it's possible the version I bought is a cracked copy too?some of my friends have this game.I install their versions to see what happens.

Comment: I believe this question shouldn't be closed as per community consensus from the [meta] post, [When does a question “support piracy and pirated games”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7546/4797).

Comment: Try Updating Your Graphic Card Driver.

Comment: When I installed the game it isn't request steam information.So I believe that it no needs steam.so answer is here!What I bought is cracked.I will kill that seller!

Comment: @Ramhound please don't pretend buying a game rather than copying it is going to fix all bugs. Sometimes problems in copied games are defects present in bought copies as well.

Comment: @mpower "*I will kill that seller!*" Woah. Easy there, buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is the version I bought is a cracked one and I don't know that.
Why a seller pirate games to this happen for me?

Comment: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3030/keeping_the_pirates_at_bay.php